# want to use mailto: function on woocommerce page

Tags: javascript, html, woocommerce, mailto

want to use mailto: function on woocommerce page,when someone clicks on image ..it should open compose page with pre written email and subject and current page url in the mail body

here is my code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'enfold_customization_extra_product_content', 25 );

function enfold_customization_extra_product_content() {
echo '<a href="mailto:someone@someone.com?subject=please check the link in the below email message body&body=[sub]" onclick="this.href =this.href.replace('[sub]',window.location)"><img src="http://sareechoice.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/mailimage.jpeg" alt="Go to W3Schools!" width="299" height="299" border="0"></a>';
}
```

i am using this code in woocommerce page but unfortunately website gave fatal error and crashed ....but if same code i am inserting in a normal html page inside body tag of html ..then its working as user is able to click on the link and open the compose page with predefault email ,subject and body with current page url .

thanks in advance

Comment: What was the exact error message ?

Comment: Nothing..website crashed.

Comment: You said, "website gave fatal error and crashed". also, have you checked error logs ?